# spring Data Jpa findFirst is failing when the method parameter data type is integer

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa and in my JPARepository interface I have used '**findFirst**' feature but it is failing when my repository method is having the **Integer** parameter.

**Repository:**

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends
    JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

Employee findFirstByAgeOrderByEmployeeId(int age);

}
```

**Entity class:**

```
@Entity
Employee{

@Id
int employeeId;
int age;
String name;

}
```

Query It is generating as following

```
select e.employeeId, e.age, e.name from Employee e where e.age = ? Order by e.employeeId limit ?
```

Getting following error

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: For
> queries with named parameters you need to use provide names for method
> parameters. Use @Param for query method parameters, or when on Java 8+
> use the javac flag -parameters.; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: For queries with named parameters you
> need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query
> method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your query isnt good : findFirstByAge"Oderder"ByEmployeeId
try "Order".

And use objects instead primitive (Integer instead int), sometimes hibernate uses getter and setters to access data.

Comment: It was Typo issue Alejandrao/